# Notification when iam policies are changed using AWS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-config

Is there a way to find out if there is a change made to any of the IAM resources(policies, users, roles) and trigger an SNS topic **other than** AWS Config recording. AWS config recording is already configured to send SNS alarm to security team, and i want to have another recording just for IAM resources.  please let me know.

Comment: What about using using [sns filter policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) to filter out IAM changes and send them to different subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch Events can send notifications when particular API calls are made, and it can send Amazon SNS messages.

See: [Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on an Event - Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html)